# Able to add to database in MongoDB but not mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am learning about Mongoose. I am working along [this tutorial](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/build-user-authentication-with-node-js-express-passport-and-mongodb) and running into a stumbling block with adding entries to my database, run through Heroku MongoDB. I am able to add to the existing collection "test1" when I load the app 'trywithmongodb' but I in my Heroku mLab console I do not see anything added to *any* collections when I access the page "trywithmongoose". Help? Here is the relevant code for in index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
app.get("/trywithmongodb", function(request,response){
    response.send("Looking at the /trywithmongodb page"); 

    var configDB = require('./config/database.js'); 
    //add to the database
    mongo.connect(configDB.url , function(err, db) {
        var shorturl = db.collection("test1");
        var date = new Date();
        var newsitejson={original_url: "accessed at", site_number: date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()}
        shorturl.insert(newsitejson)
        db.close()
        })

    });

app.get('/trywithmongoose', function (request, response) {
var configDB = require('./config/database.js'); 
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
// grab the user model
var User = require('./app/models/user');

// create a new user
var newUser = User({
  name: 'Peter ',
  username: 'peter45',
  password: 'willbehashed',
  admin: true
});

// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('User created!');
});

response.send("You are looking at /trywithmongoose");
});
```

And here's the full file user.js for the schema:

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  admin: Boolean
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: you have the mongodb connection only inside app.get("/trywithmongodb") scope! here: app.get('/trywithmongoose') you aren't connected to mongo. Mongoose connection infos can be found here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: I added a connection for mongoose but it still isn't adding anything to my mongodb when I load the page...

Comment: change this: var newUser = User({}) to: var newUser = new User({}) @garson

Comment: Thanks for trying but still no change

Comment: *"I am able to add to the existing collection 'test1' .... any collections when I access the page 'trywithmongoose'"*. So what collections do you think you are looking in for items added by your mongoose code? This line `mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` tells mongoose to use a collection called `"users"` note the **S** on the end. You show no code at all that attempts to read from this collection, but chances are you are simply looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @NeilLunn, you're right that I'm not reading it in on the page -- I am looking at https://www.mlab.com/databases/heroku_<mydatabasenumber> and I do not see a collection called 'users' I tried creating one but still nothing is being added.

Comment: I figured out the problem! I was using an outdated version of 'mongoose' I thought      npm update would fix that, but apparently not!